# How to get the run time image id to set wallpaper

Tags: java, android, image

I am using `view paper` for image gallery, able to see all the images on swipe.
Here I want to set the image as wallpaper by clicking the "Set as wallpaper" button.

### Below are the difficulties I am facing:

I am able to set the image as wallpaper successfully, but with constant image 
Ex: R.drawable.picture3.But at run time when the images are loaded at each 
turn different image will be displayed so  cannot give this constant value 
`R.drawable.picture3`.

How do I get the run time image id which is displayed?
Trying to achieve on click "Set as wallpaper" should set the current image
as wallpaper.
Note : v.getId()=R.drawable.picture1 not worked here both gave different value

Below is my code:

```
             Context context;
         Integer[] imageIDs = {
         R.drawable.picture1,
         R.drawable.picture2,
         R.drawable.picture3,
         R.drawable.picture4,
         R.drawable.picture5,

         }; 

        @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
             ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
             ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
             viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
             Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
             button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                         WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                         try {
                            wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.picture3);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Image is clicked-"+v.getBackground(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });        

        }


        public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
        Context context;
        int currentPosition;
        private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
                 R.drawable.picture1,
                 R.drawable.picture2,
                 R.drawable.picture3,
                 R.drawable.picture4,
                 R.drawable.picture5,
        };
        ImageAdapter(Context context){
            this.context=context;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return GalImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_content_inset_material);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        >
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="#cccccc"
                    android:text="@string/set_as_wallpaper" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I don't want to achieve this in instantiateItem method in image adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple.If I got it correct then you want to set the image as wallpaper after clicking the button.Then here is the logic

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    curruntPosition=arg0; //Here you can the position

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

And then

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                         WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                         try {
                            wallpaperManager.setResource(imageIDs[curruntPosition]);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Image is clicked-"+v.getBackground(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

**Edit:**

*If you want to get the current viewable image from the viewpager*

Maintain a list of images that are added dynamically say `imageList` then

```
  int currentItem =viewPager.getCurrentItem();
  Drawable drawable = getResource.getDrawable(imageList[currentItem]);
  Bitmap bm =((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
```

Comment: Hello Soham , Your solution really worked :) super and just one more question  here just want to know how to get the image id.At run time for the particular page,since here the images are static so we are getting if it is dynamic or say user added his own image then how to identify this.

Comment: @user4659578.Glad it helped. See my edited answer,it's a bit tricky.